# React-router-dom Navigation to not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I got this code. I get an warning and the code does not seem to work.

﻿
`router.ts:11 Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.`

When the page is accesed on `localhost:3000/` the code is supposed to navigate to `localhost:3000/dashboard` but it's not doing that for some reason.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still render the `Navigate` component on the `element` prop. `react-router-dom@6` `Route` components have ***only*** the `element` prop for rendering routed components. There is also no longer an `exact` prop as in v6 all routes are now ***always*** exactly matched.

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
```

Full Code

```
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```